# Is a Case statement what I need?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and trying to merge two columns into a new table based upon a simple logic. I have been attempting a variety of CASE/WHEN statements but am hitting a wall.

Table: `program` / Columns `C1, C2`

The logic must be:

[image: logic matrix]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (i.e. no images.) [mcve].

Comment: can you create a sql fiddle to show us your data and what youre trying, where your failing and what errors you are getting

Answer (score 4):

Use a `case` *expression*:

```
select c1, c2,
       case when c1 = 'Yes' and c2 = 'Yes' then 'Both'
            when c1 = 'Yes'                then 'Regional'
            when                c2 = 'Yes' then 'Local'
            else                                'No'
       end
from program
```

(The value for the first fulfilled condition will be returned.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
-- create test data in table variable @T
declare @T table 
           (
                C1 nvarchar(3) null,
                C2 nvarchar(3) null
           )

insert into @T values (null, null)
insert into @T values (null, 'YES')
insert into @T values ('YES', null)
insert into @T values ('YES', 'YES')

insert into @T values ('NO', 'NO')
insert into @T values ('NO', 'YES')
insert into @T values ('YES', 'NO')
insert into @T values ('YES', 'YES')

-- get the wanted value in RESULT columns based on C1 and C2
select 
    C1, C2,
    case 
       when ISNULL(C1, 'NO') = 'NO' and ISNULL(C2, 'NO') = 'NO' then 'NO'
       when ISNULL(C1, 'NO') = 'NO' and C2 = 'YES' then 'LOCAL'
       when C1 = 'YES' and ISNULL(C2, 'NO') = 'NO' then 'REGIONAL'
       when C1 = 'YES' and C2 = 'YES' then 'BOTH'
    end as RESULT
from @T
```

This will work in SQL Server.